# Loop through table rows to calculate totals (quantity * cost per row)

Tags: jquery

So I basically have multiple rows in the format:

```
<tr class="items" id="items">
    <td><input type="text" name="description[]" id="description[]" style="width:450px;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity[]" style="width:40px;text-align:center;" onblur="CaclulateQuantityTotal();"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cost[]" id="cost[]" style="width:40px;text-align:center;" onblur="CaclulateCostTotal();"/></td>
    <td><select name="currency[]" id="currency[]"><option value="USD">USD</option><option value="CAD">CAD</option></select></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total[]" style="width:40px;text-align:center;" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td><a href="#" id="add_item">+</a></td>
</tr>
```

I basically would like total[] to be (for that row) cost * quantity.

My problem is I know how to loop through all of the quantity[] and the currency[] separately using jquery, but I can't figure out how to match them up on a per row basis.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: First, remove the IDs from all your elements -- you shouldn't have two elements on a page with the same ID.

Comment: use .each on the "tr" to get the rows

Comment: `$('tr.items').each(function(index, cItem) { var jItem = $(cItem); jItem.find('input[name^=total]').val(parseFloat(jItem.find('input[name^=cost]').val()) * parseFloat(jItem.find('input[name^=quantity]').val())); });`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('tr.items').each(function(i,el) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $cost = $this.find('[name="cost\\[\\]"]'),
        $quant = $this.find('[name="quantity\\[\\]"]'),
        c = parseFloat($cost.val()),
        q = parseInt($quant.val(), 10), // always use a radix
        total = c * q || 0; // default value in case of "NaN"
    $this.find('[name="total\\[\\]"]').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/AtcPc/

Comment: You would need to `parseFloat()` the `.val()` as they would be strings.

Comment: They'll be automatically converted by JavaScript. However, you're right -- they probably SHOULD be parsed as integers or floats beforehand. Updated.

Comment: JS does not auto-convert in that direction generally, it will numbers -> strings, but not vice versa.

Comment: Good adding the `.toFixed(2)` - forgot about that.

Comment: It will auto convert for `* / and -`, but I agree, I always convert just incase, because and `addition (+)` will concatenate them as strings instead of do addition. Either way, +1 blaze :)

Comment: @Orbling: [JavaScript will always attempt to convert strings into numbers when performing math.](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/PGsdz/).

Comment: It does not with the addition operator generally, as @mcpDESIGNS says, it does with the other operators.  It's best practice to manually convert because of this.

Comment: @Blazemonger Can we use same id like this `id="description[]"` on dynamically added controls ? it will be treated as unique id?i am unble to get this please tell me what actually it is ?

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through $(".items"), and compare $(items[i]).children(".cost") and $(items[i]).children(".quantity") (of course, you would have to add that as a class to those inputs)

So something like -

```
var items = $(".items").get();

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
   var cost = $(items[i]).children(".cost").val() * $(items[i]).children(".quantity").val();
}
```

This may not be exact, but it should get you started.

Comment: +1 for the method; though `.children()` only matches direct children, the `<td>` would get in the way, use `.find()` to get descendant matches.

Answer (score 0):

Add the object in the function call from the HTML

HTML

```
    <tr class="items" id="items">
        <td><input type="text" name="description[]" id="description[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity[]" onblur="CaclulateQuantityTotal(this);"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cost[]" id="cost[]" onblur="CaclulateCostTotal(this);"/></td>
        <td><select name="currency[]" id="currency[]"><option value="USD">USD</option><option value="CAD">CAD</option></select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total[]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
         <td><a href="#" id="add_item">+</a></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
function CaclulateQuantityTotal(obj) {
  var $tr = $(obj).closest('tr.items');
  //you now have access to the tr the function is called from, do whatever you want!
  var $q = $tr.find('input[name=quantity]'); // gives you quantity, etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add some classes so you may get to the values easier and plus... you shouldn't have repeated IDs :)

```
        <tr class="items" id="items">
            <td><input type="text" name="description[]" id="description[]" style="width:450px;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity[]" style="width:40px;text-align:center;" onblur="CaclulateQuantityTotal();" class="quantity"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cost[]" id="cost[]" style="width:40px;text-align:center;" onblur="CaclulateCostTotal();" class="cost"/></td>
            <td><select name="currency[]" id="currency[]"><option value="USD">USD</option><option value="CAD">CAD</option></select></td>
            <td style="text-align:right;"><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total[]" style="width:40px;text-align:center;" readonly="readonly" class="total"/></td>
            <td><a href="#" id="add_item">+</a></td>
        </tr>
```

JQuery code:

```
(function () {
    $.each($('tr.items'), function(){
        var quantity = $(this).children('td').children('.quantity').val();
        var cost = $(this).children('td').children('.cost').val();
        var total = quantity*cost;
        $(this).children('td').children('.total').val(total);
    });
}());
```

Hope it helps, here's the working DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/MvFYd/

Comment: Also, you'll only need to run this onLoad and all your price totals will be calculated at once! ;)